# Fighting customer service abuse

Tags: contract-law, india, breach-of-contract

Large corporation A has contractual obligations to provide customer service by phone.

By hiring many people to continuously make fake phone calls and jam up the company's phone lines, a third party disrupts A's ability to field calls from real customers.

Would any defenses allow A to avoid liability if a customer sues A for breach of contract based on its failure to provide customer service by phone?

Comment: Do you mean something like denial of service attack?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's regarding a technical implementation or business practice.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I dont think it is, because a denial of service attack, however its done, is almost certainly against the law in many jurisdictions - you cant tie up someones phone lines, you cant block access to their buildings, you cant take down their websites etc etc etc.  There are technical implementations to mitigate these things for sure, but there are also probable legal mitigations which can be taken.

Comment: Yes but denial of service punishment if possible is good but will the bussiness be fined for breaking law if ever a law mandated something such service ?

Comment: @astackexchangeuser - Re: "if ever a law..." One can only answer what the law is not what it might be. Consider rephrasing the question to ask about current legislation.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I initially read it the same way, but I think the question is actually asking what legal defense the business would have if a customer asserted that the failure to provide customer service was a breach of contract.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires speculation about what a hypothetical customer service contract *might* say ("may provide customer service contractually") or what a future law *might* require ("if ever a law mandated...such service").

Comment: I'm puzzled by the antipathy to what really seems like a very straightforward contract question: Company A has a contractual obligation customer B. Third Party X interferes with A's ability to perform. Does A have any defenses if B alleges a breach?

Answer (score 2):

If a customer sued the company for breach of contract under the circumstances you described, the company could be able to avoid liability by asserting an [impracticability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impracticability) defense.

Under Restatement § 261, the impracticability defense excuses a party from performance when

> after a contract is made, a party's performance is made impracticable without his fault by the occurrence of an event the non-occurrence of which was a basic assumption on which the contract was made, his duty to render that performance is discharged, unless the language or the circumstances indicate the contrary.